# after update SSRS Report Viewer to V15 Toolbar Icons not displaying

Tags: asp.net, reporting-services, webforms, ssrs-2016

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kFISR.png)

my web config change code is :

```html
<controls> 
        <add tagPrefix="rsweb" namespace="Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms" assembly="Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845DCD8080CC91"/> 
      </controls>

 <buildProviders> 
        <add extension=".rdlc" type="Microsoft.ReportViewer.Common, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845DCD8080CC91" />
      </buildProviders>
 <httpHandlers>
      <add verb="*" path="Reserved.ReportViewerWebControl.axd" type="Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.HttpHandler, Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845DCD8080CC91" />
      </httpHandlers>
 <handlers> 

<add name="ReportViewerWebControlHandler" preCondition="integratedMode" verb="*" path="Reserved.ReportViewerWebControl.axd" type="Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.HttpHandler, Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845DCD8080CC91" />
</handlers>
```

and My html Code is :

```html
<div dir="rtl" id="divReport" runat="server" class="ReportViewerResult">
 <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server" AsyncPostBackTimeout="3600"></asp:ScriptManager>
    <asp:Panel ID="pnlCustomParams" runat="server" Visible="false" CssClass="CustomeParameterReportClassDiv">
    </asp:Panel>
    <rsweb:ReportViewer ID="ReportViewer1" runat="server" CssClass="ReportClassDiv" ShowToolBar="true"
        ShowBackButton="True" OnDrillthrough="ReportViewer1_Drillthrough" OnBack="ReportViewer1_Back" BorderStyle="None">
    </rsweb:ReportViewer> </div>
```

Do you know what is the solution for this problem?